# Why do I get `o` is not iterable if it returns generator object that implements `next` method from `Iterator` interface

Tags: javascript

Generator object returned by the generator function implements `iterator` interface with the `next` method:

```
function *f() {
    yield 0;
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
}

const o = {};
o[Symbol.iterator] = f();

const a = [...o];
```

I also implemented `Symbol.iterator` method on `o` to make it iterable. So why do I get `o` is not iterable error.

Comment: Seriously?! Who downvotes such a good question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the function `f` instead of passing it. Remove the parenthesis in your code block like this and try again:

```
o[Symbol.iterator] = f;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the function itself.

```js
function *f() {
    yield 0;
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
}

const o = {};
o[Symbol.iterator] = f;

const a = [...o];

console.log(a)
```